# tinymce form textarea ajax once appears once

Tags: ajax, tinymce

I have tinymce working fine on all textareas in a form; however, when I use AJAX to insert a new form the editor works "once".

I remove the div area and insert another form with ajax and only have a base form textarea. I'm trying to have forms for each row (inserted with PHP). How can I do this?

This is what I'm using:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: 'specific_textareas',
    theme: 'modern',
    editor_selector : 'mceE'
});
```

and the form:

```
"<textarea id='ta' class ='mceE' name='comment' cols='30' ></textarea>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this.. you should load `tinymce sript` again with new textarea id.

You can add time within your textarea id:

```
// Add below code inside your callback 

var day = new Date();
var textarea_id = "ta_" + day.getTime();

$(node).html("<textarea id='"+textarea_id+"' class ='mceE' name='comment' cols='30' ></textarea>");

tinyMCE.init({
    mode: 'specific_textareas',
    theme: 'modern',
    editor_selector : "#"+textarea_id
});
```

Comment: After trying my code on IE, it works fine, but Firefox does not. I should mention that I use php-pdo from a DB to assign an ID to each textarea. Not sure why IE works and FF does not, seems backwards from all other issues.